# Problem with calculating probability values in python

Tags: python, math, operators, probability, bayesian

This code is a part of bayesian classifier application with python. I'm trying to calculate probability of each word with respect to each class. 
`word_prob` variable here, multiplies all the probabilities for each class (we have 6 classes here). When i print `word_prob` in the loop, i get a small probability value in each iteration which are correct. but when i use `*=` operater, the final probability value is multiplied by 2 which is very weird! Why does that happen? Can someone help? 
Thanks in advance

```
for c in range(1,7):
  word_prob = 1
  for k,v in enumerate(training_data_matrix[0][:-1]):
      word_count = 0
      if v in filtered_words:
         for doc in training_data_matrix[1:]:
            if doc[-1] == str(c):
                word_count += int(doc[k])
         print(v,int(word_count)+1,len(filtered_words))
         word_prob *= ((int(word_count)+1)/len(filtered_words))
         print(word_prob)
  print(c, 'probability is',word_prob)
```

And this is the result:

comp 3 114 
0.02631578947368421 
network 1 114 
0.00023084025854108953 
ucsd 1 114 
2.0249145486060484e-06 
1 probability is 2.0249145486060484e-06

Answer (score 0):

you get the probability 0.00000202491454860605. Does it makes sense to you. I can see the ratio between each result is 114. i.e res1/res2 = 114, res2/resv3 = 114

try printing the statement by formating
`print("{:.20f}".format(word_prob))`

Comment: ok thanks.I'll format them on printing. But 114 is number of words. in fact the probabilities are computed this way: 3/114 - 1/114 - 1/114. these three probabilities are multiplied and resulted in 2.0249145 !! Why?!!

Comment: you are missing something the exponential notation.  its  2.0249145486060484e-06 or 0.00000202491454860605 not 2.0249145

Comment: (3/114) * (1/114) * (1/114) == 2.0249145486060484e-06

Comment: :) Execuse me. I didn't notice the minus sign. Thanks a lot